# Not able to retrieve form data from jetty post request

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, jetty, jetty-8

I am trying to add Azure AD authentication support to an existing jetty application. I am redirected to my application post authentication with Azure AD and the request looks like this

[image]

Dump of my request object looks like

```
org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request@46b8a08d[  
   _async=org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncContinuation@26bb9274@DISPATCHED,
   initial,
   _asyncSupported=true,
   _attributes=   {  
      javax.servlet.request.key_size=128,
      javax.servlet.request.cipher_suite=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
      javax.servlet.request.ssl_session_id=5cAbFe3eCbFfA8Ca84A546Cb995105F012E83eD556A493E55973F5A074A91eE3
   },
   _authentication=<null>,
   _baseParameters=   {  

   },
   _characterEncoding=<null>,
   _connection=AsyncHttpConnection@b7de4c,
   g=HttpGenerator   {  
      s=0,
      h=-1,
      b=-1,
      c=-1
   },
   p=HttpParser   {  
      s=-5,
      l=5,
      c=0
   },
   r=1,
   _context=ServletContext@o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler   {  
      /,
      null
   },
   _newContext=false,
   _contextPath=,
   _cookies=<null>,
   _cookiesExtracted=false,
   _dispatcherType=REQUEST,
   _dns=false,
   _endp=SSL NOT_HANDSHAKING i/o/u=0/0/0 ishut=false oshut=false   {  
      AsyncHttpConnection@b7de4c,
      g=HttpGenerator      {  
         s=0,
         h=-1,
         b=-1,
         c=-1
      },
      p=HttpParser      {  
         s=-5,
         l=5,
         c=0
      },
      r=1
   },
   _handled=false,
   _inputState=1,
   _method=GET,
   _parameters=   {  

   },
   _paramsExtracted=true,
   _pathInfo=<null>,
   _port=0,
   _protocol=HTTP/1.1,
   _queryEncoding=<null>,
   _queryString=<null>,
   _reader=<null>,
   _readerEncoding=<null>,
   _remoteAddr=<null>,
   _remoteHost=<null>,
   _requestAttributeListeners=<null>,
   _requestedSessionId=<null>,
   _requestedSessionIdFromCookie=false,
   _requestURI=<null>,
   _savedNewSessions=<null>,
   _scheme=https,
   _scope=org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher-142075f1,
   _serverName=<null>,
   _servletPath=/token,
   _session=<null>,
   _sessionManager=<null>,
   _timeStamp=1554775615151,
   _dispatchTime=0,
   _timeStampBuffer=<null>,
   _uri=/token,
   _multiPartInputStream=<null>
]
```

I have tried to iterate over header and attributes but getting only `Connection` in header and `javax.servlet.request.key_size, javax.servlet.request.cipher_suite, javax.servlet.request.ssl_session_id` in attributes

My call trace looks like

```
java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace(Thread.java:1559)
com.AzureADLoginService.login(AzureADLoginService.java:33)
org.eclipse.jetty.security.authentication.LoginAuthenticator.login(LoginAuthenticator.java:47)
org.eclipse.jetty.security.authentication.BasicAuthenticator.validateRequest(BasicAuthenticator.java:90)
org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:492)
org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1088)
org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:429)
org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1020)
org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:154)
org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:370)
org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:494)
org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:971)
org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1033)
org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:644)
org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235)
org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)
org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SslConnection.handle(SslConnection.java:196)
org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:696)
org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:53)
org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I wrote a sample jettey server app and I am able to retrieve token(code in form data, refer attached screenshot) using `request.getParameter("code")` but its not working with my application, can someone please help me out.

I am using jetty 8.1.15.v20140411 and don't have freedom to upgrade it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, [Jetty 8 has been EOL (End of Life)](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/what-jetty-version.html) since November 2014.

Now, to look at your `Request` state ...

```
   _inputState=1,
   _method=GET,
   _parameters=   {  

   },
   _paramsExtracted=true,
```

Those 4 tell us that your Request ...

1. was a `GET` method (which isn't to spec, as GET methods should not have a request body).
2. `inputState` at `1` says that some piece of code used the `.getInputStream()` putting the request body content in STREAM mode.
3. `paramsExtracted` says that some piece of code used one of the various `.getParameter*()` methods.
4. `parameters={ }` means that there were no parameters extracted or present either from the request query string, or the request body content.

Recommendations ...

- First make sure you use the appropriate http method for what you are attempting to accomplish, use `POST`.
- Ensure that any other code hasn't used the request body content before you (such as a filter)
- Ensure that your `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` body content is sane and without encoding errors!  (Jetty 8 was far more lenient, but that leniency made it vulnerable to many security issues.  Jetty 9 is very strict)

If you can debug a live scenario, then set a breakpoint on `org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.getParameters()` and follow along with what it's doing.